# How to decode RFID value?

Tags: rfid, encryption, pi-pico-w

I am working on an attendance system project using `Raspberry Pi Pico W`, `EM - 18 reader` and `MicroPython`.

Not sure of the tag type here, but I guess it is 125KHz tag. More, my card is keeping  `'29714856'` actual value. But when read using EM - 18 I found it to be `'0113A70CA811'` encoded value.

I tried to decode using hex, binary to bring back the actual value, but didn't succeed.

Comment: if you have an android phone with NFC capability ... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc

Comment: Hi @jsotola appreciate your comment, as I m working with 125 KHz, the app is not able read that type of tags.